# .zslogin is not sourced on a zsh startup

Tags: zsh, ubuntu-16.04, terminator, prezto

I am using zsh on Ubuntu with [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto). Whenever I start a new terminal my `.zlogin` file is not being sourced. I added lines like `echo "%filename - in"` and `echo "$filename - out"` to beginning and end of all files that I believe should be sourced on a startup. That's what I get when a new terminal (or terminator or xterm) window is started:

```
zshenv - in
zprofile - in
zprofile - out
zshenv - out
zshrc - in
zpreztorc - in
zpreztorc - out
zshrc - out
```

It looks to me that there are no errors during sourcing of these files (otherwise, there would be an unmatched pair of "in" and "out" lines). Please, help me to find out why I do not see "zlogin - in" and "zlogin - out". Thanks in advance!

By the way, I use identical startup files on a macOS machine and it works as intended.

Comment: Your terminal is not a login shell.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell

Comment: Oh, thank you! I was so sure that it is a login shell that did not bother checking =)

Comment: Mac OS terminal emulators tend to start login shells, because they are not themselves started from an environment inherited from a login shell.